# A span element which takes more width then the text needs

Tags: html, css

I have a span element and a text inside of it, when inspecting its CSS you can see that this span takes more space then the text inside of it needs. [image] . in this image the text is alinged to center.

i want that the span fits the text. i tried to set the span to

```css
span {
  background-color: #d9376e;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span>code</span>
```

but that did not work.

Any suggestion please.
thank you.

Comment: your css is wrong, adding a comma before the span makes it applicable to `class="span"` not span component

Comment: thank you, i fixed that it was just a typo :)

Comment: Please update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The current code doesn't reflect your issue

Comment: Please provide all necessary code to reproduce your issue. what you provided here does not create this behavior since [span is an inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) and will take up as much space as required for its contents. (if not affected by other things)

Comment: The code provided works for me

Comment: As others stated, the snippet shows the span as you would want it to appear. I assume some other CSS rules apply to your span, which leads to the extra space. Inspect the element with your browser's [developer tools](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/how-to-inspect) and you should quickly find the source of the issue.